# open fragment from recyclerview item click activity

Tags: java, android

When I click on the item of the activity's recyclerview to open to fragment. However, the data of the activity still does not disappear. Is there any way to fix it. Here is my code:

```
PhotoDetailFragment photoDetailFragment = new PhotoDetailFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("data", photo);
photoDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_activity_layout,photoDetailFragment)
                                  .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for pass value to fragment,

```
public class PhotoDetailFragment {

private Object data;

public static getInstance(Object data) {
   this.data = data;
   return new PhotoDetailFragment();
}


PhotoDetailFragment() {
}

}
```

or

```
public class PhotoDetailFragment {

private Object data;

public setData(Object data) {
   this.data = data;
}


PhotoDetailFragment() {
}

}
```